# Arduino Client connects to server through websocketsocket but can't communicate with it

Tags: python, websocket, arduino, client, esp8266

I have this client running on a esp8266 wifi board, here's the code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;
String line="";

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(10);

    // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
    WiFiMulti.addAP("MYSSID", "MYPASSWORD");

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Wait for WiFi... ");

    while(WiFiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(500);
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    delay(500);
}

void loop() {
    const uint16_t port = 5021;
    const char * host = "192.168.x.yyy";
    
    Serial.print("connecting to ");
    Serial.println(host);

    // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
    WiFiClient client;

    if (!client.connect(host, port)) {
        Serial.println("connection failed");
        delay(1000);
        return;
    }

  // This will send the request to the server
  Serial.println("Connected!!!!!");
  const char * frame = "009TEMSDS&000001001023";
  client.print(frame);
               
  delay(1000);

   while(client.available()){
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
  }

  //Serial.println(line);
    Serial.println("closing connection");
    client.stop();
    
    delay(1000);
}
```

I want it to connect to a python websocket server on my computer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio
import websockets
import threading

framesReceive = []

async def receiver(websocket, path):
    framesReceive = (await websocket.recv())
    print(framesReceive)
    # dictFrame = frameBreakdown(framesReceive)

    await websocket.send("pong")

# Socket Server thread
def ThreadServer():
    asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
    start_server = websockets.serve(receiver, "192.168.x.yyy", 5021)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

threadServer = threading.Thread(target=ThreadServer, args=())
threadServer.start()
```

In a nutshell the message "009TEMSDS&000001001023" is not being sent, and the response "pong" is not being received.

[Even if a connection is in fact being established(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpISv.png)

[and when i try to send the same message from a client within my computer it works as expected(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfHLT.png)

Am i missing something?
Why is the client's message not being recieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESP8266 code you shared is not using a websockets client. It's using a raw TCP connection. `WiFiClient` just opens a TCP connection to a server; it provides neither HTTP nor websockets over that connection. You'll need another library that uses `WiFiClient` to do this.

If you want to use websockets to communicate with your Python code you'll need to use a websocket client on the ESP8266. I have to wonder, why? Websockets are mostly used to get around limitations of web browsers - you do not need to use websockets for an ESP8266 to communicate with a Python script on the same network. The more common use case for websockets would be for Javascript running in a browser to communicate with a websocket server.

There are a few different ESP8266 websocket client libraries out there; use Google to find one that is still supported and suits your needs. It's possible that [this library](https://github.com/hellerchr/esp8266-websocketclient) might work for you.

I would recommend that you simply rewrite your Python server to use accept a raw TCP connection and not worry about using websockets in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it, i ended up using [this one](https://github.com/morrissinger/ESP8266-Websocket)